# Is there any reasons for using MySQL over MariaDB?

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, mariadb

this is the first time that I ask a question here.

*Is there any reasons for using MySQL over MariaDB ?*
I am currently using MariaDB (Everywhere home and pro) since Debian (Stretch) is no longer offering MySQL. (
I must say that I really like MariaDB and use it everywhere and never had any trouble with it.

If I understand correctly, MariaDB is still designed for migrating from MySQL.
Beside that MariaDB and MySQL have a [lot of variance](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-105-and-mysql-80/).

To this day, I still see some people using MySQL , some like Oracle products and don't really see reasons for using MariaDB and others don't really care I guess.

Personally, I prefer MariaDB for the ease of use and I always had some weird trouble with MySQL for weird reasons unfortunately. Not to mention,  I don't particularly care for Oracle products. Installation and maintaining have always been a pain, MariaDB [bash script](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-package-repository-setup-and-usage/) is working really great.

Other(s) reason(s), could be performance, articles/graphs are saying that MariaDB is faster, in my opinion, it must really depend for what. People that want performance hate both with what I've seen.

So, what do you prefer in *2022* and why ? :)

Thank you,

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL come from the same original source code before it forked several years ago. MySQL is a paid product at heart and provides paid support, training, and a bunch of other stuff (like RedHat).  MySQL has a nifty workbench for working with the database too.  I myself have never had anything but problems with compatibility with it.  Install one part and it breaks stuff in my distro.  Fix that and it breaks other stuff.. on and on.  MariaDB is built and packaged with distros and I have had very few problems with it (thus never needed support) or fought compatibility.